# ImageView.getLayoutY() wrong value?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a little problem I hope you can help me with:

[image: Screenshot from my program]

In this Scene, That blue circle is a 128x128 ImageView, this ImageView is in an HBox, and the HBox is in a VBox, I then set the VBox alignment to Pos.CENTER;

Everything's ok, but when I print the layoutY of the ImageView, it says 0 instead of a 61 (Scene's height is 250, so the layoutY should be 125 - 64);

Does someone have an idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't be zero? Is there anything above it in the `HBox`?

Comment: Updated, also no, anything else is present, just an ImageView, an HBox and a VBox!

Comment: I even tried translating the ImageView in the HBox, I centered it and correctly returned a layoutX of 296 (Scene's width is 720), but layoutY still 0.

Comment: If nothing else is in the `HBox`, (and by default, even if something else is in there) then the image view will be at the top of the `HBox` and will have `layoutY` equal to zero. Why do you think it would be non-zero?

Comment: Translations are applied independently of the layout coordinates, so changing `translateY` will not affect `layoutY`.

Comment: Uhm... maybe I did not quite understand how those methods work: I'd like to get the X and Y of the corner of that ImageView, referring to the Scene (in this case, it should be (0, 61)): what's the proper way of doing that?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `layoutX` and `layoutY` properties determine the layout position of a node within its parent: in this case, the layout position of the image in the `HBox`. Since there is nothing else in the `HBox`, the image view will just be at `(0,0)` in the coordinate system of the `HBox`, so you will just get `0` for the `layoutY` property.

(Note also that transforms, such as translations, are applied independently of the layout coordinates - if you like to think of it this way, the node is laid out, then transforms are applied which will alter its final position. So transforms do not modify the `layoutX` and `layoutY` properties.)

To get the location of a node in the scene, you can use the `localToScene` transform to convert a point in the node's own coordinate system to a point in the scene's coordinate system. So to get the location of the top left (`(0,0)`) of the image view in the scene, you can do

```
image.localToScene(new Point2D(0, 0))
```

Here is a complete SSCCE (just using a plain `Region` to stand in for the image view):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BoundsInSceneExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        Node image = createImage();
        hbox.getChildren().add(image);
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().add(hbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 250);

        // force the layout, so layout computations are performed:
        root.layout();

        System.out.printf("Layout coordinates: [%.1f, %.1f]%n", image.getLayoutX(), image.getLayoutY());
        Point2D sceneCoords = image.localToScene(new Point2D(0,0));
        System.out.printf("Scene coordinates: [%.1f, %.1f]%n", sceneCoords.getX(), sceneCoords.getY());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Node createImage() {
        Region region = new Region();
        region.setMinSize(128, 128);
        region.setPrefSize(128, 128);
        region.setMaxSize(128, 128);
        region.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        return region ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Output:

```
Layout coordinates: [0.0, 0.0]
Scene coordinates: [0.0, 61.0]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.